# PHP Prepared statement error "Number of bind parameters do not match number of number of fields in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli

Im trying to use a prepared statement for a query.
The code is as follows

```
<?php
$studentrollno=1;
$studentclass=10;
$studentsection='A';
$host="localhost";
$dbName="school_election_db"
    $conn=new mysqli_connect($host,dbName); 
    if(conn->connect_error())
    {
        echo "error occured";
    }
    else
    {
        $stmt="SELECT * FROM voting_details where studentrollno=? and 
    studentclass=? and studentsection=?";
    $conn->bind_param($studentrollno,$studentclass,$studentsection);
    $result=$conn->execute();
    if(result==true)
    {
    echo "login succesfull";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Please try again";
    }
    ?>
```

The error is around the mysqli query but i'm not able to figure out the error.It work properly when i used normal statements with procedural PHP.But i read that the normal way to do it was using OOP and prepared statements.
The error i'm getting is "mysqli_bind_param():: The number of elements in the statement does not match the number of bound parameters".

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script.

Comment: Your code as listed here is riddled with syntax errors. You may want to show the exact code giving you your error.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're getting that error.  You should be getting a parse error with that code.

Comment: Your code has many syntax error. Should we assume it is just wrong copy paste?

Comment: i have edited everything..i  hope everything is correct now now

Answer (score 3):

You should use prepare

```
$dbName="school_election_db"
$conn=new mysqli_connect($host,dbName); 
if(conn->connect_error())
{
    echo "error occured";
}
else
{
    $stmt=  $conn->prepare("SELECT * 
        FROM voting_details 
        where studentrollno = ? 
        and  studentclass = ?
      and studentsection = ? ") ;
$stmt->bind_param('iis',$studentrollno,$studentclass, $studentsection);
$result=$stmt->execute();
if($result==true)
{
echo "login succesfull";
}
else
{
echo "Please try again";
}
?>
```

Comment: might want to address the syntax error -> `and  studentclass = ?"; and studentsection = ? ") ";`

Comment: You're missing the bind types: `bool mysqli_stmt::bind_param ( string $types , mixed &$var1 [, mixed &$... ] )`

Comment: this is not a coding service  .. looking to the code  .. seems correct but only you can check if work right

Comment: @aynber  added  param type too

Comment: is your code OOP style..Im asking becuase in bind parameter part you have written PDO:PARAM_INT.Sorry for asking such lame questions..im a beginner :)

Comment: @EverythinginoneChannel  correct answer  updated  for mysqli binding